# python access second element of list

Tags: python

When I print my list I get something like this

`[[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]]`

I want to extract first and second elements from above list into separate lists so that I can ask the plt to plot it for me.

So my results should be 
`[6.0,6.1,6.2 ... 6.8]` and `[0.5,1.0,1.5,2.0 , ... .4.5]`

I  want to know if we have a cleaner solution than to

```
for sublist in l:
    i=0
    for item in sublist:
       flat_list.append(item)
       break #get first element of each
```

Comment: Are you unaware of list indexing? `sublist[0]`? You're using a really weird way to get the first item of a list. You might want to go through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), or browse the docs for the built-in [types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) and [functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) a bit.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try `list indexing`:

```
data = [[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]]
d1 = [item[0] for item in data]
print d1
d2 = [item[1] for item in data]
print d2
```

output :

```
[6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8]
[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 12):

[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will provide the required output.

```
xy = [[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]]
x,y = zip(*xy)
print(x)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
(6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8)
(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5)
```

`zip()` aggregates the elements from all the iterable. `zip(x,y)` would provide the list you currently have. `zip()` with `*` can be used to unzip a list.

Also, **there is no need to convert the tuples to list** since `pyplot.plot()` takes an `array-like` parameter.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using numpy arrays. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a= np.array([[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]])

plt.plot(a[:,0], a[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: Output]

Answer (score 4):

Here a try with zip, `zip()` will makes iterator that aggregates elements based on the iterables passed, and returns an iterator of tuples, so `map()` function is used to make the tuples to list :

```
l = [[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]]

a,b = map(list,zip(*l))
print(a,b)
```

O/P will be like :

```
[6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8]  [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l = [[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]]
a,b=list(zip(*l))
print('first elements:',a)
print('second elements:',a)
```

To plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = [[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]]
a,b=list(zip(*l))
print('first elements:',a)
print('second elements:',a)
plt.plot(a,b)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

One-liner using [`zip` built-in](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
>>> original = [[6.0, 0.5], [6.1, 1.0], [6.2, 1.5], [6.3, 2.0], [6.4, 2.5], [6.5, 3.0], [6.6, 3.5], [6.7, 4.0], [6.8, 4.5]]
>>> left, right = zip(*original)
>>> left
(6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8)
>>> right
(0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5)
```

if you are embarassed that results are `tuple`s we can turn them into `list`s simply using [`map` built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> left, right = map(list, zip(*original))
>>> left
[6.0, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8]
>>> right
[0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of pure Python approaches here.  But given that your goal is to plot the separated values, I think there's a case to be made here for the simplicity of Pandas - just drop the list as-is into a data frame and `plot()`:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data).plot(x=0, y=1)
```

[image: plot]